# For each language another permalink (Wordpress+qTranslate)

Tags: wordpress, seo, qtranslate

I need a plugin for wordpress who makes it possible to have for each language another permalink.
I need this for pages in wordpress (and with compatibility with qTranslate).

For example:

```
DE: http://example-page.com/de/treten-sie-mit-uns-in-kontakt
EN: http://example-page.com/en/contact-us
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qtranslate slug could do the trick.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate-slug-with-widget/

Comment: This is posible whith .htaccess right now not have plugins. Qtranslate slug is only for widgets.